# How to make a C++ map with class as value with a constructor

Tags: c++

I have a class that has a constructor. I now need to make a map with it as a value how do I do this? Right now without a constructor I do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class testclass {
public:
  int x = 1;
};

int main()
{
  map<int,testclass> thismap;
  testclass &x = thismap[2];
}
```

If I added a constructor with arguments how would I add them to the map? I basically need to do

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class testclass {
public:
  int x = 1;
  testclass(int arg) {
    x = arg;
  }
};

int main()
{
  map<int,testclass> thismap;
  testclass &x = thismap[2];
}
```

This obviously wouldn't work since it requires an argument but I can't figure a way of doing this.

Comment: Can you show the constructor and the errors you are facing? Did your class have a default constructor?

Comment: @kuro I edited the question. I just need to be able to add a class to the map but with a constructer in the function. I provided an example of what I need above.

Comment: you need a default constructor as well in this case

Comment: @kuro the whole point is that I need to pass in some values at the initialization. So I need to use a constructor with arguments.

Comment: the way you are using map, needs the default constructor. Check out the answer by dreamlax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how you can add items of your own class to your map.
Note : I used a string in testclass to better show difference
between key and value/class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

class testclass
{
public:
    explicit testclass(const std::string& name) :
        m_name{ name }
    {
    };

    const std::string& name() const
    {
        return m_name;
    }

private:
    std::string m_name;
};

int main()
{
    std::map<int, testclass> mymap;

    // emplace will call constructor of testclass with "one", and "two"
    // and efficiently place the newly constructed object in the map
    mymap.emplace(1, "one"); 
    mymap.emplace(2, "two");

    std::cout << mymap.at(1).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << mymap.at(2).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Reading through the other answers I see that I cannot use the [] operator but only the at operator correct?

Comment: You can if you add a default constructor to testclass. However [] has the risk that you accidentally create a new entry where you don't want one

Comment: I see. I added a default constructor so now it works. with the [] operator

Answer (score 3):

Using [`std::map::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at) requires that the mapped type is default-constructible, since it must be able to construct an element if one doesn't already exist.

If your mapped type is not default-constructible, you can add elements with [`std::map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace), but you still can't use `std::map::operator[]` to search, you will need to use [`std::map::find()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find) or so.

Answer (score 1):

That's a rather obvious feature of std::map (and very similar other std containers). Some of their **operations** require specific type requirements for good reasons.

There is no problem to create such a map as you suggest in the first place, however, you are restricted to method calls that do not require potential default construction. The `operator[]` is such a method, since in the case the element is not found, it is created. That is what does not work in your example. Just use other methods with little impact on the map usage and you can still succeed:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

class testclass {
public:
  int x = 1;
  testclass(int arg) {
    x = arg;
  }
};

int main()
{
  map<int,testclass> thismap;
  thismap.insert( {2, testclass(5)} );
  
  auto element2 = thismap.find(2);
  if (element2 != thismap.end()) {
    testclass& thiselement = element2->second;
    cout << "element 2 found in map, value=" << thiselement.x << endl;
  }

  auto element5 = thismap.find(5);
  if (element5 == thismap.end()) {
    cout << "no element with key 5 in thismap. Error handling." << endl;
  } 
}
```

Main issue: avoid `operator[]`.

**Note**:

Looking at the other very good answers, there are a lot of methods that can be used without default construction. There is not "right" or "wrong" since this simply depends on your application. `at` and `emplace` are prime examples that are highly advisable.